# django - use environment variables in debian not working

Tags: python, django, debian, environment-variables

It might be simple thing but I just can't seem to get it running.

in my Django project's settings, I have these db settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PWD'),
        'HOST': 'xxxx.yyyyy.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

and in `/etc/environment` I have set the variables and also in `.profile`.

but this is just not working and I am getting:

```
(1045, "Access denied for user 'www-data'@'132.31.48.116' (using password: NO)")
```

If I remove and hardcode the credentials, it works. so obviously my env variables are located in wrong place. can someone please give some look at it?

I am using Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28) x86_64 in ec2 server

Comment: do you run Django in the shell or inside docker container? What's the output of **env** command?

Comment: @DmitrySemenov I have also set variables inside .env. django app is not dockerized.

Comment: How is the app being launched? manually (shell) or using something like `supervisord`? because it influences the environment variables that the process has access to.

Comment: @dethos good point! app is ran by uwsgi emperor.